# How many different combinations can be made by assigning subsets for each member of a larger set, such as for peer reviewing?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine we have a set of ***n*** participants for some sort of peer reviewing, where each of these participants will be reviewed by a subset of (and thus also review) ***m*** others, where 0 < ***m*** < ***n*** , and it's our job to assign who should review who.

Note that a participant should never review themselves, and all participants should get ***m*** different reviewers.

For example, if we have 4 participants, A, B, C and D with ***m*** = 2. Then one such valid combination of reviews is:

- A reviewing B and D
- B reviewing A and C
- C reviewing A and D
- D reviewing B and C.

But it would be invalid to assign A to review B and C, B to review A and C, and C to review A and B as that would not only force D to review itself, but also to do so twice, when no participant should review any other twice.

So my question is, how many possible valid ways are there to assign reviews depending on the values for ***n*** and ***m***?

Thanks